# Properly Registering Errors in Contact Form

Tags: php, forms, contact-form

So I have a contact form that a user would fill out or not before submitting it. I have a PHP script that will perform the validation of what is entered instead of Javascript for greater security. I am having the PHP script encode the array into JSON format before passing it off to Javascript. I want Javascript to handle displaying the error messages accordingly and PHP only to handle the validation and sending of email (when successful).

The issue I am having is a good way to register the errors properly before passing it off to Javascript. Here is the PHP form I have so far (it has been edited to remove the printing of error messages):

```
<?php
ob_start();
/* Put Here email where you will receive Contact message*/
$yourEmail = "email@email.com"; // <== Your Email
$secret = 'LALALALAALALALALALALA'; // <==Your recaptcha Privte Key
/*---------------------------------------*/

// ---------------------Start the recaptcha ------------------------------------//
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && ($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
        session_start();
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$captcha&remoteip=$ip");
    $result = json_decode($response,TRUE);
        if($result['success'] == 1){
            $_SESSION['result'] = $result['success'];
            }

// --------------------End Of the Captcha Check------------------------- //

/////////////Showing all errors in array : DO NOT DELETE THIS
$formerrors = array();
///////////////////This Array will Hold all errors

// Start Captcha
if(!isset($_SESSION['result']) || $_SESSION['result'] == 0){
    $formerrors[] =  'Captcha Error';
}
//end Captcha


// remove this to make name not required
if(empty($_POST['name'])){
$formerrors[] = "Name Cannot be empty";
}
// End name


// Remove this to make email not required
if(empty($_POST['email'])){
  $formerrors[] = "Email Cannot be empty";
}
// End of email

// Remove this to make email not required
if(filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == FALSE){
  $formerrors[] = "Make Sure Email is valid";
}
// End of email

// Remove this to make Phone not required
if(empty($_POST['phone'])){
  $formerrors[] = "Phone Number Cannot be empty";
}
// End of Phone



// Remove this to make Phone not required
if(!is_numeric($_POST['phone'])){
  $formerrors[] = "Phone Is not valid";
}
// End of Phone



// Remove this to make Message not required
if(empty($_POST['message'])){
   $formerrors[] = "Message Cannot be empty";
}
// End Of Message


// Remove this to make Subject not required
if(empty($_POST['subject'])){
   $formerrors[] = "Select a subject First";
}
// End Of Subject



/* Your New inputs */

    // CODE HERE

/* end of new Inputs*/




// End Showing Errors In Array

//JSON Encode
echo json_encode($formerrors);


if(count($formerrors) == 0){
 // Saving data in variable :
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $title = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    /* Your New inputs */

        // $newinput = $_POST['new-input'] // new-input same as ID and ajax

    /* end of new Inputs*/

    //If No Error in the Array Start Sending the email
    $to = $yourEmail;   // Email to receive contacts
    $from = $email;
    $subject = 'Contact Form Email : ' . $title;
    $message = '<style>
                body{background-color:#fefefe}
                .email-style {padding: 30px;background: #fafafa;font-size: 18px;border: 1px solid #ddd;width: 60%;margin: auto;}
                p {padding: 15px 0px;}
                </style>

                <div class="email-style"><p> '.$title . '</p>

                <p>Contact Full Name : '.$name . ' </p>

                <p>Contact Email : '.$email . ' </p>

                <p>Contact Phone Number : '.$phone . '</p>

                <p>Message : '.$message . ' </p>

                <p>Cheers,</p>
                <p>'.$name.' Via Contact Form</p></div>';

    $headers = "From: $from\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
       if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ){
            echo "sent";
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
          } else {
                   echo "The server failed to send the message. Please try again later.";
                }
              }
            }
ob_flush();
?>
```

Can anyone please suggest a method of registering the error messages properly and cleanly?

Comment: Are you calling the PHP-script using Ajax? Also, using `ob_start()` and `ob_flush()` seems unnecessary in this context.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It will transfer the information over to the Javascript so yes.

Comment: Add all relevant code, including the Ajax part. You should also be consistent with what you return. Currently, you're always echoing a json array (if no errors, it will echo an empty array `[]`) but then you also echo strings later on in the script.

Comment: Create one array `$response = ['errors' => [], 'message' => null];` and add the errors to `$response['errors'][] = 'errors';` If the mail is sent, add that to the `message` and if it fails, set the error to the `errors` array like before. Then in the end of your file, you just need to `echo json_encode($response);`. Then you can just check if you have any errors or not in the response.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson but my confusion is with the registration of errors to an array.

Comment: What do you mean? You're already storing the errors in an array and then echoing them as a json-array. Except from the above mentioned issues, the PHP does what you want so if you can't handle them in the response, then it's your JS that needs work. Since you haven't posted your JS, it's pretty impossible for us to know what's going on.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson so like this: $errors = array();
  if ($errors['message'] != "")
    echo $errors['message'];

Comment: Since you're refusing to show all the parts of your code, I'm out. I'm not gonna sit here and guess.

Comment: @magnuseriksson not refusing. I just left the office and posting from my phone. I'll be by a computer in 30 or so minutes